# Java: Lazy object storage with auto key from stack trace

Tags: java, ejb, callstack

I implemented a mechanism for lazily calculated objects, just with a ConcurrentMap of ConcurrentMaps as an EJB Singleton:

```
@Singleton
public class LazyObjectStore {
    
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object>> lazyObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getOrCreate(String key, Supplier<T> supplier) {
        // create the holder
        lazyObjects.computeIfAbsent(key, i -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object> holder = lazyObjects.get(key);
        // we use the integer 0 as the key in our holder map, so we use computeIfAbsent
        // to call the supplier at most once
        holder.computeIfAbsent(0, i -> supplier.get());
        return (T)holder.get(0);
    }
}
```

Now I can use my lazy Object store in my other EJBs, for example:

```
public class MyServiceBean {
   
    @Inject private LazyObjectStore objectStore;

    public void soSomething() {
        // some code before
        // ...
        MyComplexCalculatedResult calculationResult = objectStore.getOrCreate(
                "b58be0e0-b26f-4775-a002-f285f42177f2", // just use a generated UUID here
                () -> performComplexCalculation());
        // some code after
        // ...
    }
}
```

So this complex calculation in performComplexCalculation() will be done only in the first call of my `doSomething()`.

It works good, but there is still the problem that I need an unique id for each place
where I want to use my `LazyObjectStore`. So the question is: Can I use the Java Stack Trace to find the place where I called `getOrCreate()` and then use this stack trace element as the key.

So I modified my map for the lazyObjects:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<StackTraceElement, ConcurrentMap<Integer, Object>> lazyObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

And now in my `getOrCreate(...)` method I determine the StackTraceElement in a "bogus" manner:

```
public <T> T getOrCreate(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    StackTraceElement key = StackWalker.getInstance(Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
            .walk(stackstream -> stackstream
                .filter(stackFrame -> (!stackFrame.getClassName().startsWith(LazyObjectStore.this.getClass().getCanonicalName())))
                        .filter(stackFrame -> stackFrame.getClassName().startsWith("de."))
                        .map(StackFrame::toStackTraceElement)
                        .findFirst()
                        .get());
}
```

I can use this idiom to find the point of the code where I call the `getOrCreate`-Method of my object store; and I can omit the UUID key:

```
    public void soSomething() {
        // some code before
        // ...
        MyComplexCalculatedResult calculationResult = objectStore.getOrCreate(
                () -> performComplexCalculation());
        // some code after
        // ...
    }
```

This works on my code because I develop for a german institution, so my code will always be in packages starting with "de.".

My questions are:

1. Is there a better solution to find the point in the code? Especially in EJB context where there are a lot of proxy calls between the `objectStore.getOrCreate()`-call and the first line of code in `getOrCreate`?
2. Will there be a condition where my code fails? I am currently using this during integration test but I don't dare me to use this in production code. Where are the caveats?

Comment: for questino 2: That `de.` filter either [A] is useless, or [B] will mistrigger on any library hosted on a german domain. Either way, it's bad. That cannot be the right answer. Indeed, this code should never be moved to production. What

Comment: @rzwitserloot I need that `de.` filter to find my code point in the stack trace where I called the `getOrCreate(...)` method. It is very hard to "count" the number of stack trace points in EJB context. So is there maybe a better filter to find the correct stack trace element?

Comment: You don't own `de`, Torsten. You asked 'how can it fail'. One of the many answers is: "Your filter either does nothing or finds not just your code, but any code whose project is hosted at the german ccTLD". `de.torstenfehre.myproject` or whatever your project's domain is, is at the very least required here.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I just should use my `de.` filter more precise and then it should work.